# File Not Found Exception while fetching from other package

Tags: java, file, io

I am trying to access .xls file located in my vat package. Here is code which one i m using

```
          String fileName=this.getClass().getResource("/resource/vat/form_dvat_31.xls").toString();
```

But it shows following exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/gautam/workspace/application/bin/resource/vat/form_dvat_31.xls (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
```

However when i m using path from local computer ,It works fine.

Comment: We need to know your project directory structure for this. is your src folder and resource folder at same level?

Comment: Yes ! both are at same level.When i am searcing via terminal i can found the file under bin folder.

Comment: try using /../resource/vat/form_dvat_31.xls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ***getResourceAsStream*** instead of ***getResource()*** - that gives you an InputStream directly. Alternatively, keep using ***getResource()*** if you want the URL for something else, but then use ***URL.openStream()*** to get at the data.

Answer (score 0):

When you load a resource using the `Class.getResource()` method and the resource name is started with "`/`", the method will load using an absolute path of the resource name.

In your case, the .xls file should be placed under a `resource.vat` package in your `src` directory to make it available in the same directory under the `bin`.

More on: [Location-Independent Access to Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)